# Mysql with Django Setup

Tags: python, mysql, django, terminal

I'm having problems setting up a django project on my mac os x 10.5. I've been following the recommendations on [This Site](http://anthonyscherba.com/site/blog/django-mysql-install-mac) and have had a little success. I have been able to successfully install mysql, mysql-python, and django separately. When I try to run `Applications/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p` to setup the mysql server (as in point 8 in the linked article), I get the error:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Any help on how to fix this so I can connect django / mysql and start developing locally? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this related thread can help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-m

Comment: Also note that the link you supplied is almost 2 years old--things can change in that period of time. Always try to be reading something that is current and applies to *your* specific environment.

Comment: Thank you. but still cant solve this issue. I looked through the linked stackoverflow article, but `mysql.server start` isnt found, and also not using homebrew for the install.. I am open to trying an easier installation method: any sources for an easier installation would be appreciated. I want to use Mysql/ Django locally on mac os x 10.5

Comment: Is homebrew the recommended method for installing mysql and django together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes mysql.sock is in a different location. You can sym link it to /tmp/mysql.sock

Shut down mysql.

Execute:  ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock

Start mysql back up.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to switch the sym link and start mysql. Still getting the ERROR 2002: Can't connect to mysql server. Also, I cannot find a file called mysql.sock.. Any suggestions for me? If you know any better methods or links that might help me get django and mysql working together on my mac 10.5 I would greatly appreciate it. I have been trying to get this project configured but have had great difficulty. Thank you

Comment: Have you looked in /private/tmp for mysql.sock? Sorry, it's hard to be sure since I don't have any 10.5 machines left.

Comment: Or /usr/local/mysql/run ? Also, sometimes mysql.sock is called mysql_socket.

Comment: Is `_mysql.so` the file I'm looking for on 10.5? found that in the mysql-python directory.. but no mysql_socket

Comment: I don't think so. That is likely a library. have you looked in /var/mysql ?

Comment: Also have `mysql_com.h` and `mysql.h`. Thank you for your input on this difficult issue.

Comment: .h is a header file. Not relevant.

Comment: I haven't found a folder named `var`

Comment: Should be at the root of the directory structure.

Comment: Any references that would be of help? I have followed instructions on at least 5 different sites but have not been able to set up my mysql with django on my machine. Very frustrating. It seems like local installation should be simpler with highly developed programming languages.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you are doing local development on your machine (with the idea of deploying to a server later) you might want to think about using sqllite as a database instead of MySQL. Much easier to set up. You could still deploy to a server running MySQL later and only have to change some settings in settings.py (your views etc would all stay the same).

Comment: My Macintosh HD has the folders 'Applications', 'Developer', 'Library', 'System', 'User Guides and Information', and 'Users'

Comment: open up a terminal window and type "cd /" then type "ls" and tell me what it says

Comment: Applications   dev
Desktop DB   etc
Desktop DF   home
Developer   mach_kernel
Library    mach_kernel.ctfsys
Network    net
System    private
User Guides And Information sbin
Users    tmp
Volumes    usr
bin    var. Thank you for your input

Comment: Found mysql.sock in tmp through terminal

Comment: You're welcome. I remember having a similar problem years ago. I think it may even have been on 10.5! They were dark times for MySQL on OS X. Anyway, you will notice the 'var' directory there. You also have 'private'. Try typing 'ls private/tmp'. See if mysql.sock is listed there. If not then try typing 'ls var/mysql' and do the same.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Scrace. Found `mysql.sock` and made the sym link as you described in your answer above. Now I get `ln: /tmp/mysql.sock: File exists` so I'm pretty sure the link is valid, but still not sure how to get the server started

Comment: Are you saying that you found mysql.sock in a location other than /tmp/mysql.sock?

Comment: Sorry no I found mysql.sock exactly where you said I would. in /tmp/mysql.sock Just not sure show to configure it to start the server